# Replace # character in the address bar

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting

How can I change the `#` character in the address bar to something else? For example `/` or `? P =`?

- From: `/Category/4797/kondicionirovanie#6`
- To: `/Category/4797/kondicionirovanie?p=6`

Project on asp.net core.

Comment: You tagged this as `url-rewriting` but server site rewrite rules don't have access to the fragment identifier (`#` and everything after it) in the URL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.